# Вывести несколько объектов на яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, java, yandex-maps-api

Это часть написана на java.
У меня post контроллер возвращает список координат
[x,y], [x,y] ....  по переданному радиусу.

например сколько поликлиник в нашей БД в радиусе 500 метров. и возвращаются объекты.

Мне нужно отобразить страницы с картой где эти объекты расположены.
Для одного объекта я пишу

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>3d9ad8d98c7bbaf.html</title>

    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1000px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.17/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init(){

        var myMap;

        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [59.5,30.315946],
 zoom: 15,
            behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom'],
            controls: ["zoomControl", "fullscreenControl"]
        });

        myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

        myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {
            position: {top: 15, left: 15}
        });

    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

а как сделать вывод сразу нескольких объектов?

спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
//создаем точки (несколько штук)
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([50.76, 36.64], {
            hintContent: "подсказка",
            balloonContent: "контент балуна"
        });

        myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([50.77, 36.64], {
            hintContent: "подсказка",
            balloonContent: "контент балуна"
        });

        //добавляем к карте
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark2);
```